# checking return json object for data typescript and angular2

Tags: json, angular, typescript

so i have made a call to check and see if i return an object with actual data in it - I am not sure if i am doing this wrong but this is what i am trying.

Here is my get call i have made to my services - COMPONENT FILE:

```
resultData: any = [];
barChartLabels: any =[];

getData(){
    this.dataService.getData().subscribe((data) => {
       this.resultData = data; 
       for(let item of this.resultData) { 
           this.barChartLabels.push(item.name);
       }
    }
}
```

I am currently seeing `this.resultData` in my console but know after pushing item's name into another array which is used in binding in my html it is not being displayed.

Here is my service call - SERVICE FILE:

```
getData(){
        return this.http.get('my url')
            .map((res:Response) => res.json());
    }
```

Here is also what i have in my json file:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Test 1",
    "score": 34
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Test 2",
    "score": 92
  }
]
```

This is my html:

```
<canvas baseChart [datasets]="barChartData" [labels]="barChartLabels" [options]="barChartOptions" [legend]="barChartLegend" [chartType]="barChartType">

  </canvas>
```

This may have transitioned into a different topic now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular2)

Comment: I reformatted your code above to make it easier to read and in so doing saw you were missing a closing brace. So if you copied this code directly from your project, you'll need to add the additional closing brace.

Comment: @DeborahK thank you.

Comment: So did that fix your issue? Or is it still not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want it to be in the component, then the code needs to be in the body of the arrow function. Something like this:

```
getData(){
    this.dataService.getData().subscribe(data => {
       this.resultData = data;
       for(let resultItem of this.resultData){
         console.log(resultItem);
       }
    })
  }
```

This is because the subscribe is asynchronous. When the getData method first runs, `this.resultData` has no value. It isn't until the Http response is returned that `this.resultData` is set.

Comment: I was able to follow this structure to see my object return in the console. So what if i want to push all the `names` from what i returned into a new array so i can use that to populate my graph - can i do it here or is there a way better way of doing this task? I will update my post to reflect updates

Comment: This did solve the issue of seeing whether i get data back or not - but i noticed that when i replace the console.log with  a push (pushing resultItem to a new array - after the call the array i pushed data into becomes empty or undefined. Why is that?

Comment: Could you put together a plunker showing your new issue?

Comment: Iguess what i am trying to get to is in my `getData()` how can i use `this.resultData` outside of this function? whenever i try to reference `this.resultData` it is always empty

Comment: And the code you showed above should work. So a Plunker may help figure out why it doesn't.

Comment: My first time creating  a plunker so hopefully i got it right. https://plnkr.co/edit/zQB05EmHaBoJ35LMQYD4?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `do` operator to see the data that is returned. You could try something like this:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

...

getProducts(): Observable<IProduct[]> {
    return this._http.get(this._productUrl)
        .map((response: Response) => <IProduct[]> response.json())
        .do(data => console.log('All: ' +  JSON.stringify(data)))
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```